# Is there a quick way to see (not jump to) the definition / type of a symbol in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I know about <kbd>cmd-double-click</kbd>, and use it all the time, it's great. But is there an easy way to make Xcode simply tell me the type of a symbol in a popup or similar without having to jump away from my current position in code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>option</kbd>+click should get you there for standard documentation.

For user symbols, not sure. You could <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+click to open the definition in an Assistant editor, in Xcode 4+.

Comment: Option-click definitely seems to be the best there is. I certainly miss being able to mouseover an identifier and have its declaration pop-up somewhere :(